# Users are unable to open my Google Script web app

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created an app script as an web app with doGet function. Its working fine with no issues. But when I am sending that link to my friends its opening the Google docs login page instead of UI.

The link I am giving to my friends is the one which is shown after clicking 'deploy as web app', is labeled as 'Current web app URL'. And at the pop up screen which pops when we click 'Deploy as web app' button, i set that anyone have access to the app and I am accessing the app as 'User accessing the app'.

Comment: Do your friends have an active session in the browser with a gmail.com account for example?

Comment: I dont think so.
Srik is right that I had to change the permission to Anyone including anonymous.

Comment: If your friends are not sign in with an account from gmail.com or similar, it was necessary to change the permission to include anonymous. Good for the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the access permission to `Anyone` means 'Anyone with a gmail or Google Apps account' and it is therefore they are required to sign in. HOwever, if you set it to `Anyone including anonymous`, your friends need not sign in.